# How to install latest libcurl on debian server?

Tags: debian, libcurl

I'm kind of new to these things. I do not know what command line is required to install latest version of libcurl.
I followed few articles found on net but i get No acceptable C compiler found in $PATH.
I'm on a debian server. Please help.

Comment: https://packages.debian.org/jessie/curl

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
su -
apt-get update
apt-cache search ^libcurl
apt-get install <whatever_apt-cache_listed>
```

And be sure to check Google first, before asking these basic questions here.

**EDIT:** Thanks @x-yuri for pointing out the `su` vs `su -` difference, it slipped through my fingers when I wrote this :-)

Comment: Using su is a bad habit, use [su -](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/7021) instead

Comment: Using `su` is a bad habit.  Use `sudo` instead.  Then, you don't have to share root's password all over the place.

Comment: on Debian systems there is no `sudo' by default. You cannot assume the user has it installed, therefore the provided solution is granted to work on every Debian machine. I hope that clarifies why I haven't used it. In the event sudo is installed, yes, I recommend using it instead of su-ing the tty.

Comment: Google is what led me here.

Comment: Please don't advise people to do an apt-get update.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the source code [here](https://curl.haxx.se/download.html#Linux), and compile it

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

You'll be in the last version

Answer (score -14):

Type in terminal:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install php5-curl
```